# What's the Actual Code for Receptacles Below Counters in Peninsulas

Tags: kitchen-counters, nec

I'm installing a kitchen that'll have a peninsula and I'm wondering about section 210.52(c)(5) where it says that "...receptacles mounted below a countertop must not be located where the countertop extends more than six inches (150 mm) beyond its support base".

If I've got this kind of situation (the counter is 12" deep): [image: Counter Mockup]

can I install a receptacle a few inches in on the half-height wall (so that it's still under the counter, but not a full 12" in)?

Comment: What do you imagine being plugged in there and how would you expect its cords to be routed?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Where are you located?

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the welcome--I'm in Seattle. And Harper, it'll be a workspace, so probably blenders or something like that--not imagining anything that'll sit there long-term like a toaster or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer based on the NEC in the US:

> Can I install a receptacle a few inches in on the half-height wall (so that it's still under the counter, but not a full 12" in)?

Yes, that's almost right. As long as you are not more than 6" in laterally off the counter edge you are fine.

Also, the receptacle cannot be more than 12" down from the counter top.